# How to distinguish out of memory versus out of address space in C on Linux?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, 32-bit, virtual-address-space

Suppose I'm running a piece of code on a 32 bit CPU and plenty of memory. And a process uses `mmap` to map a total of 2.8GB worth of file into it's address space. Then the process tries to allocate 500MB of memory using `malloc`. The allocation is bounded to fail and returns `NULL` due to not having enough address space; even though the system may have enough allocate-able memory.

The code looks something like this:

```c
int main()
{
    int fd = open("some_2.8GB file",...);
    void* file_ptr = mmap(..., fd, ...);
    void* ptr = malloc(500*1024*1024);

    // malloc will fail because on 32bit Linux, a process can only have 3GB of address space
    assert(ptr == NULL);
    if(out_of_address_space())
        printf("You ran out of address space, but system still have free memory\n");
    else
        printf("Out of memory\n");
}
```

How could I detect the failure is caused by out of address space instead of allocate-able memory? Is `out_of_address_space` possible to implement?

Comment: `malloc` on a standard system manages virtual memory and not physical memory. So any out of memory errors it gives is by definition address space related and not physical memory related.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Edited

Comment: Don't `mmap` the *entire file* at once.

Comment: `How could I detect the failure is caused by out of address space instead of allocate-able memory? ` I guess you could see like if `MemFree` in `/proc/meminfo` is greater then the memory you want to allocate. Och, maybe query `/proc/$$/maps` and sum 3rd column and see if it's lower then the size?

Comment: I know how to solve it. But I want to be able to detect it so I *know* such problem exists programmatically. Otherwise debugging it is a nightmare.

Comment: Why can't you change your program to `mmap` less memory? Or else convince management to switch to a 64 bits Linux system and buy more RAM. It probably is cheaper than recoding

Comment: I can `mmap` less memory. But I have a code base that is full of these mmaps. So I need a way to detect when it happens and show appropriate errors. And I really want to move to 64bits. But I have to support legacy systems :-(.

Comment: The only indication you have is mmap() failing (returning (void*)-1) and then checking errno. errno==EINVAL appears to be the condition you need, but it is used for some other conditions. In any case there is no way out for your program, except for mmap()ing less, or releasing some mappings.

Comment: @MaryChang:  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62277660/edit) your question to explain **why do you need to  `mmap`  such a big file entirely ??**  I believe it is a design bug. Without such a motivation, your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

> How could I detect the failure is caused by out of address space instead of allocate-able memory?

You could calculate the amount of maximum virtual memory like [bash does in ulimit -v](https://github.com/geirha/bash/blob/master/builtins/ulimit.def#L624) - by querying `getrlimit()`.

You can calculate the amount of "allocated" virtual memory by summing the differences between second and first column in `/proc/pid/maps` file.

Then the difference will give you the amount of "free" virtual space. You can compare that with the size you want to allocate and know if there is enough free virtual space.

Example: Let's compile a small program:

```
$ gcc -xc - <<EOF
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    void *p = malloc(1024 * 1024);
    printf("%ld %p\\n", (long)getpid(), p);
    sleep(100);
}
EOF
```

The program will allocate 1MB, print it's pid and address and sleep so we have time to do something. On my system if I limit virtual memory to 2.5M the allocation fails:

```
$ ( ulimit -v 2500; ./a.out; )
94895 (nil)
```

If I then sum the `maps` file:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/94895/maps | awk -F'[- ]' --non-decimal-data '{a=sprintf("%d", "0x"$1); b=sprintf("%d", "0x"$2); sum += b-a; } END{print sum/1024 " Kb"}'
2320 Kb
```

Knowing that the limit was set to 2500 Kb and the process is using 2320 Kb, there is only space to allocate 180 Kb, not more.

Possible C implementation for fun:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t address_space_max(void) {
    struct rlimit l;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &l) < 0) return -1;
    return l.rlim_cur;
}

size_t address_space_used(void) {
    const unsigned long long pid = getpid();
    const char fmt[] = "/proc/%llu/maps";
    const int flen = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, pid);
    char * const fname = malloc(flen + 1);
    if (fname == NULL) return -1;
    sprintf(fname, fmt, pid);
    FILE *f = fopen(fname, "r");
    free(fname);
    if (f == NULL) return -1;
    long long a, b;
    long long sum = 0;
    while (fscanf(f, "%llx-%llx%*[^\n]*", &a, &b) == 2) {
        sum += b - a;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return sum;
}

size_t address_space_free(void) {
    const size_t max = address_space_max();
    if (max == (size_t)-1) return -1;
    const size_t used = address_space_used();
    if (used == (size_t)-1) return -1;
    return max - used;
}

/**
 * Compares if there is enough address space for size
 */
bool out_of_address_space(size_t size) {
    return address_space_free() < size;
}

int main() {
    printf("%zu Kb\n", address_space_free()/1024);
    // ie. use:
    // if (out_of_address_space(500 * 1024 * 1024))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> And a process uses mmap to map a total of 2.8GB worth of file into it's address space. Then the process tries to allocate 500MB of memory using malloc.

### Don't [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the entire file at once !

Do `mmap` no more than one gigabyte (and no more than 2.5 gigabytes in total on a 32 bits Linux, including `malloc`-related `mmap` or `sbrk`). Then use [mremap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) and/or [munmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html). See also [madvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). Be aware of the `m` modifier to [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) mode string. In *some* cases, [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) functions (using `fseek` and `fread`) might be enough and you could replace your `mmap` with them. Be aware of [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) and of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). Both could be tunable thru `/sys/` or `/proc/` (see [sysconf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html), [sysfs(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) and might be monitorable thru [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) or [userfaultfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) and/or [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Notice that [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [shared libraries](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) are also `mmap`-ing (thru [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)...) - and some `malloc` implementations are *sometimes* using [sbrk(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) to manage small memory chunks. As an optimization, [free(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) does not always `munmap`. Check with [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) (or programmatically thru `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/status` or `/proc/self/statm`, see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

Some 32 bits Linux [kernels](https://kernel.org/) could be specially configured (at their compile time) to accept slightly more than 3GBytes of [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). I forgot the details. Ask on https://kernelnewbies.org/

**Study the source code of your C standard library** (e.g. [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)). Most of them are [open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) so you can improve them, e.g. [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/). You could use others (e.g. [dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)), and you usually can redefine `malloc`. Budget a few months of efforts.

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (also [here](https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/advancedlinuxprogramming)), [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), the documentation of *your* [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library),  and a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: Thanks. In any case, is there a way to implement `out_of_address_space()` so I know is is not a real OOM but address space issue programmatically?

Comment: My `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`  don't have any `out_of_address_space` symbol (Debian/x86-64/Sid) so I don't understand your comment

Comment: Pardon. I meant how to implement a function that returns 1 if an allocation fails by not having enough address space. And returns 0 otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Code your own `malloc` / `free` and study the source code of existing ones. Most Linux [standard C libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) are open source, and you are allowed to improve them. I am not sure it is a good idea.